¿Como evitar la aparicion de una ventana al usar selenium en pyton?
He estado haciendo un programa usando selenium y chrome.Quiero poder ejecutarlo sin que aparezca una ventana. He visto en la documentacion que lo podía hacer así:
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)

driver.get("https://www.avanzabus.com/")

time.sleep(40)

El problema es que me sigue apareciendo la ventana. Aunque si es verdad que está completamente en blanco sin representar la web. Además la ventana no se puede ni mover, ni redimensionar ni nada. Y al minimizar VS code se minimiza también.
Esta es la ventana:

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque me pasa esto?

¿Intentaste lo que se menciona en el blog de selenium? (--headless=new)

@padaleiana Si, sigue sin funcionar. He probado todas las combinación de poner y quitar los -- y el new

Tras buscar mas al respecto he encontrado en los foros de selenium que el problema podría ser causado por la nueva versión de chromeDriver al utilizar el nuevo modo headless. En pocas palabras y sin entender del todo la causa del problema se puede solucionar cambiando --headless=new por --headless=old.
Al parecer no es un problema que me esté pasando solo a mi asique si alguien llega a esta pregunta, en estos enlaces puede ver más información:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/14438
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/14457
